# Xamarin.Forms Android app SQLite data disappears

Tags: c#, android, database, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I am writing a Xamarin.Forms app for Android using C#. I setup the Sqlite dB at: System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal

When the app is deployed on device I can add data and then retrieve it. 
However, when I check the app next day(offline, without debugging from pc) all the dB data is gone.

Does it mean that the dB file is gone after some time?

Comment: Have you tested on another device?

Comment: No. I have only one device

Answer (score 0):

Data from DB should not gone.
Are your sure that your DB initialization code is ok? Maybe every time you started the app, tha data is restoring to some start state?

Answer (score 0):

The mysterious dissappearance of data in a sqlite db can have multiple causes.

Make sure that your db file exists, maybe you can implement a small debug button somwhere which will throw an alert which tells you if the file exists.

However using System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal shouldn't be the cause, I use that folder for my apps as well.

Second, do you actively commit your transactions? Especially when your app gets backgrounded, i would recommend calling Commit() in order to make sure that every pending transaction gets written into database, since you never know when the garbage collector comes around while your app is backgrounded.

If you are working with multiple threads, make sure that you are opening your database in a mode supporting a multithreaded environment.
If you open your sqlite db with a simple

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path);
```

the database will open single-threaded.
Try this instead:

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path, SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.NoMutex);
```

If that doesn't help, please give a bit more insight into your code (how do you open the db, how do you insert/update data, etc...)